# Typescript compiler 1.0RC gives Unable to get value of the property 'toLowerCase'

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm

I just tried to compile a 0.9 ts project with the ts 1.0 exe but get this when my file watcher is run:

"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/TypeScript/tsc.exe" --sourcemap Common.ts --module
tsc.js(55958, 21) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'toLowerCase': object is null or undefined

The exe is defined where the visual studio plugin installed it, maybe I need to use the node one instead? but when I point the file watcher to the node version is complains that its not an .exe

Comment: I also made a video about TypeScript modules to help beginners : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `--module` flag but not specifying a module type (hence `undefined`). Use `--module commonjs`

Comment: @FutuToad can you do me a favor and run `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/TypeScript/tsc.exe` and tell me the version? I cannot reproduce this error and neither can the typescript team : http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2247